# Progress monitor (Indeterminate) to show execution happens at backend

Tags: java, multithreading, process, progress-bar, processbuilder

I am executing an external process at the backend using Processbuilder in my  java program.I am using process.waitFor to get the exit status of the process. The backend process 'll take time which depends upon the input provided.so i need to make a progressbar for indeterminate time until the process completes. This is just to notify the user that there is a process going on at back end.

```
    try {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        this.progressbar.setVisible(true);
        this.progressbar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        perform(this);
    }
}                                    

public void perform(JFrame f)
{
            String cmd[]={"cmd", "/c","a.exe:};
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            pb.directory(new File(dir_path));
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            try {
                    p = pb.start();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(execution.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                       }
            try
            {
               int exitVal = p.waitFor();
               if(exitVal>0)
               {
                   this.progressbar.setVisible(false);
                   this.progressbar.setIndeterminate(false);
                   this.button.setEnabled(true);
               }
               if(p.waitFor()==0)
               {
                   this.progressbar.setVisible(false);
                   this.progressbar.setIndeterminate(false);

                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"Scan completed successfully.");
               }
             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(execution.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

Button is the name of my button which invokes the call. But the problem I'm facing is the function call perform is made without executing these statements.

```
    try {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        this.progressbar.setVisible(true);
        this.progressbar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Button is disabled after the execution of that function.
1) may i know why that happens?
2) may i know the solution to make progressbar indicating the backend progress until it completes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would maybe try to refactor this, so it's using a `SwingWorker`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a `SwingWorker`. It's made for problems such as this. Here is a snippet from some code from my codebase (`vui` is a JFrame):

```
vui.clearOutput();
vui.setOutput("Waiting for items to copy...\n"
            + "This could take several minutes. Please standby...");
vui.disableExit();
vui.disableInput();
vui.disableNext();
vui.showProgressBar();

// make thread so you can disable all options when zipping and enable progress bar
SwingWorker transferWorker = new SwingWorker() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("resources/bin/transferCopier.bat");

            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VaderController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Logger.getLogger(VaderController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ie);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void done() {
        vui.hideProgressBar();
        vui.clearOutput();
        vui.setOutput("Transfer Complete!\n\n"
                    + "Push \"Exit\" to quit.\n\n");
        vui.enableExit();
        mode = VaderMode.END;
    }
};
transferWorker.execute();
```

When `transferWorker.execute();` is performed, `doInBackground()` is invoked. Once `doInBackground()` is done doing its computations, `done()` is then invoked. `done()` is where you would do any final updates to the GUI.

The key things to note about my code above is that I enable the progress bar before executing the `SwingWorker` then when the `SwingWorker` is done executing, I disable the progress bar.

Resources:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 0):

It is executed, but it is executed in the same thread as the GUI, so the view does not get updated.

After showing the ProgressBar and disabling the Button start a runnable that waits for the Process to finish.

Simply wrap `perform()` in a Runnable.

untested code: 
instead of `perform(this)` you write:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        perform(YourClassName.this);
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: now am able to get the progress monitor but the control does not goes to the function(perform).

Comment: Did you `start()` the Thread? I edited my answer to include an untested Example how i would try to do this.